# Why is my model shrinking when weight painted?

Tags: weight-painting

The body part shrinks when touched by the brush. I am using blender 2.66.

[image: Image of shrunken arm mesh around bone]

Comment: One reason could be because you are posing the model as you are weighting it. Hard to say exactly without having a look at the model as this could be caused by several things.

Comment: Most likely that the scale of the armature is not equal to the scale of the mesh.

Comment: The real reason was that hat the scale of the armature is not equal to the scale of the mesh. It should be possible to weight while posing and I have been trying. The real reason was that hat the scale of the armature is not equal to the scale of the mesh.

Comment: @user3576 You can write an answer then.

Answer (score 1):

This issue arises when the armature and the mesh have different scales. To fix that, press Ctrl+A and then select *Scale* from the menu.

[image: apply scale]

This will apply the scaling so there is a zero scaling value. If you do this for both the mesh and the armature, then this issue should be resolved.